# vastly different run times on different machines

Tags: compiler-construction, parallel-processing, mpi

Background: I was tasked to write an MPI program in C that calculates all the primes up to a given number. This program runs correctly.

I compile the program using openmpi and the -O3 optimization.

When running it on my personal computer (Ubuntu 11.10 x64) using 1 process, I get the results I expect (~13 seconds for all the primes up to 4E9). The same is true for my CS department's machines.

However, when I run it on Carver at NERSC, the time jumps dramatically (~61 seconds for 1 process).

I have tried using both the openmpi and intel compilers...no difference. I got it to run with the proper times once, but I don't remember what (if anything) I did differently and there was a slight index error in my code that I have since fixed (not related to actually performing the computation, so the timings were accurate).

I've tried to be as clear as possible; if you have any more questions, I'd be happy to answer. Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MAX(x,y)   ((x)>(y) ? (x) : (y) )
#define MIN(x,y)   ((x)>(y) ? (y) : (x) )

#define A(i,j)     A[(i)*M+j]
#define b(i)       b[i]
#define c(i)       c[i]

long* preamble(long N,char* mark){
N = sqrt(N)+1;

long   size;
long   curr, index;
long   i, j,n;
long   count;
long* primes;

//Pierre Dusart proven upper bound for number of primes up to N
//found at http://primes.utm.edu/howmany.shtml
size = (N/log(N))*(1+(1.2762/log(N)))*sizeof(long);
primes = (long *)malloc(size);

if(N%2)
    n=N/2 - 2;
else
    n=(N-1)/2 -1;

index = 0;
curr = 3;

while (curr*curr<=N) {
    for (i=(curr*curr-3)/2; i<=n; i+=curr){
        mark[i]=1;
    }
    while (mark[++index]) ;
    curr = index*2+3;
}

/*number of primes*/
count = 0;
for(i = 0; i <=n; i+=1){
    if(mark[i] == 0) {
        primes[++count]=i*2+3;
    }
}
primes[0]=count;
return primes;
}

long FMIB(long p, long b){
if(b%p==0 && b!=p) return b;
long i = b + p - b % p;
if(i%2){return i;}else{return i+p;}
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

long N  =      4000000000;
long BKSIZE =  500000;

char *mark;

long *primes;
long *loopprimes;

long   size, offset;
long   numprimes;
long   i, j, n, ii, start, index;
long count, total;

double time;


if ( argc > 1 ) N  = atol(argv[1]);
if ( argc > 2 ) BKSIZE = atol(argv[2]);

int id, p;

BKSIZE = (BKSIZE-3)/2 +1;

if(N%2)
    n=N/2 - 2;
else
    n=(N-1)/2 -1;

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &id);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p);

MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

if(id==0) time = MPI_Wtime();

size = (n/p+1)*sizeof(char);
mark = (char *)malloc(size);

for (i=1; i<=n/p+1; i++){
    mark[i]=0;
}

primes = preamble(N,mark);

if(id!=0){
    for (i=0; i<=n/p+1; i++){
        mark[i]=0;
    }
}

offset = (1+n/p)*id;

numprimes=primes[0];
if(id==0){
    start = (sqrt(N)-3)/2+1; //mark index to start at
}else{
    start = offset;
}

//MAIN COMPUTATION - BLOCKING
    for(ii=start; ii<=MIN(ii+BKSIZE,offset+n/p); ii+=BKSIZE){
        for(j=0; j < numprimes; j++){
            for(i=(FMIB(primes[j+1],ii*2+3)-3)/2; i<=MIN(ii+BKSIZE,offset+n/p); i+=primes[j+1]){
                mark[i-offset]=1;
            }
        }
    }

/*number of primes*/
if(id==0){
    count = 1;
}else{
    count = 0;
}
for(i = 0; i <= n/p && (i+offset)*2+3 <= N; i++){
    if(mark[i] == 0) {
        ++count;
    }
}

MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Reduce(&count, &total, 1, MPI_LONG, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

if(id==0){
    time = MPI_Wtime() - time;
    printf("There are %ld primes less than %ld\n", total, N);
    printf("First three primes:");
    j = 1;
    printf(" %d", 2);
    for ( i=0 ; i <= n && j < 3; i+=1 ) {
        if (mark[i]==0){
            printf(" %ld", (i*2+3));
            ++j;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
if(id == p-1){
    printf("Last three primes:");
    j = 0;

    for (i = n-offset; i >= 0 && j < 3; i--){
        if (mark[i]==0){
            printf(" %ld", ((offset+i)*2+3));
            j++;
        }
    }
    if(j < 3){
        printf(" %d",2);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
if(id == 0){
    printf("Elapsed time: %f seconds\n",time);
    fflush(stdout);
}
MPI_Finalize();
//free(mark);
return 0;
}
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/csh

#used for intel compiler
#module unload pgi openmpi
#module load intel openmpi-intel mkl
make clean
make

set x = "sieve_mpi"
set n = 4000000000
set b = 500000

foreach p ( 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 )

cat > ${x}${p}.pbs <<EOF

#PBS -q regular
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=8
#PBS -l walltime=00:01:00
#PBS -N ${x}${p}
#PBS -e err/${x}${p}.err
#PBS -o out/${x}${p}.out

#used when using intel compiler
#module unload pgi openmpi
#module load intel openmpi-intel mkl

cd \$PBS_O_WORKDIR

echo ${x}
echo ${p}

mpirun -np ${p} ${x} ${n} ${b}

EOF

qsub ${x}${p}.pbs

end
```

Makefile:

```
CC = mpicc
EXEC = pi_cyc pi_block sieve_mpi
OBJS = 
H_FILE = 
MATHFLAG = -lm
FLAGS = -O3
SEQFLAGS = -O3

all: $(EXEC)

pi_cyc: pi_cyc.c $(OBJS) $(H_FILE)
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -o $@ pi_cyc.c $(OBJS) $(MATHFLAG)

pi_block: pi_block.c $(OBJS) $(H_FILE)
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -o $@ pi_block.c $(OBJS) $(MATHFLAG)

sieve_mpi: sieve_mpi.c $(OBJS) $(H_FILE)
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -o $@ sieve_mpi.c $(OBJS) $(MATHFLAG)

clean: 
    rm -f *.o *.pgm $(OBJS) $(EXEC)
```

Comment: The code for this shouldn't be very big. Just post it. My first guess is that one compilation is optimizing something that another isn't. That could come from different compilers, different flags, different environment variables, and many other things. Also, you don't state what hardware your system has, the CS department's hardware, or Carver's. If Carver is some wacky Itanium system, I can easily believe it might be that much slower.

Comment: Carver - http://www.nersc.gov/systems/carver-ibm-idataplex/
CS Machines - HP-xw6600-Xeon5450-SAS (8 processing cores)
My machine - AMD Phenom II 1090T

And as far as Carver being slow, the sequential version of this program, compiled with the intel compiler, completes in about 7 seconds. The MPI implementation with 1 process should be right around the same time.

Comment: posting code and script shortly

Answer (score 1):

You have way too many barriers, don't you?  Delete every single one of them.

- If you want to measure time, take the time from every process and MPI_Reduce with  MPI_MAX to rank 0 once you are done.
- The barriers around MPI_Reduce accomplish nothing.  MPI_Reduce is collective and will impose whatever synchronization is needed
- You are trying to get rank 0 and the last rank to print out stuff.  Can you maybe just have rank 0 receive those three primes  from the last rank and print that out with the rest of rank 0's output?

Edit: sorry, forgot to answer the question.  I think those barriers are slowing you down on Carver.

Comment: I didn't know I did not need a barrier before the MPI_Reduce(), but we were told to put a barrier before the MPI_Wtime(). The other barriers are just for printing purposes (which take almost no time). If it was something with the code, I would think it would be slow across all platforms, but it's not. It's only slow on Carver.

Comment: ah, i missed that you are running with a single process.  then yeah, barrier will be a no-op.  Perhaps a tool like  gprof, TAU, or HPCtoolkit will help you understand where the slowdown comes.

Comment: Barriers are relatively fast anyway (single-digit milliseconds on the hugest Cray systems). The primary reason people see a lot of time spent waiting in barriers is that their applications have load imbalance - some ranks do more work before entering the barrier than others. That said, they're not useful around the reduce, but they will help ensure consistent timing (i.e. everyone's ready to start, or has finished) when used for that.

Comment: Barrier's deceptive, though: all it says is that everyone entered.  No promises when a processes leaves the barrier.  That's why I prefer timing all the processors separately and collecting time (max, average, whatever's appropriate) at the end.

Comment: Just for fun, I removed the barriers. The results were the same. I also looked up the different compilers available on the system. I have tried gcc, icc and pgi, all with and without intel's MKL. I still am unable to get the results on Carver that I am on my department's machines. The only thing I haven't tried is scp'ing the compiled executables over to Carver and running them. However, the assignment has been turned in, and I don't want to waste any more of  my time allotment than I have to. Thanks anyways.